# black formatter: How can I place one newline before and after function instead of two

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-black

I am using [black formatter](https://github.com/psf/black). I have two newlines before and two newlines after function definition. I want one newline before and one newline after function definition.

Can i do it using black config file `black --config FILE`. If so,how.

Comment: From the description: "Black is the uncompromising Python code formatter. By using it, you agree to cede control over minutiae of hand-formatting.".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using black formatter this is NOT possible. From it's documentation:

> By using it, you agree to **cede control** over minutiae of hand-formatting._

[Current style:](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#)

> It uses 2 lines to visually distinguish methods from empty lines in code structure.  From the docs: *Black will allow single empty lines inside functions,  [...] It will also insert proper spacing before and after function definitions. It’s one line before and after inner functions and two lines before and after module-level functions and classes.*

From: [the docs of black.readthedocs.io](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#empty-lines)

[Customization:](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html#command-line-options)

> Command line options
> Black has quite a few knobs these days, although Black is opinionated so **style configuration options are deliberately limited and rarely added**. You can list them by running black --help.

You need to change the formatter you use to something different to get your effect.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was down voted.  It seems like a reasonable answer based on the documentation.  What's more, the author even seems to have switched tooling instead of continue with the requested software.

Comment: @slbass That is SO in a nutshell  - it is just silly points and I got enough so  ::shrug::

Answer (score 3):

OP here, I ended up using `yapf`.

The command looks like:

```
yapf --style={blank_lines_around_top_level_definition=1} file_name.py
```

for multiple arguments:

```
yapf --style={based_on_style=pep8} --style={blank_lines_around_top_level_definition=1} file_name.py
```

In vscode you can use the `yapf` styles like:

```
"python.formatting.yapfArgs": [
    "--style",
    "{based_on_style: pep8, blank_lines_around_top_level_definition: 1}"
],
```

If the previous does not work then please try (you will need yapf extension for this):

```
"yapf.args": [
    "--style",
    "{based_on_style: pep8, blank_lines_around_top_level_definition: 1}"
],
```